# Can the ancilla for Qiskit's mcx with mode="recursion" be dirty?

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-gate, circuit-construction, ibm-quantum-devices

I think their implementation is close to the one from [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9503016.pdf) which does use a dirty ancilla, but I just want to make sure

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to say no, since Qiskit code itself seems to [append pre and post-gate instruction chain of gates in case `dirty_ancilla` is passed to the chain MCX](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/2c402dd5c22e5e0191e3b56ddb8921abb6a90e30/qiskit/circuit/library/standard_gates/x.py#L1073) which is [not the case for `recursive` MCX](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/2c402dd5c22e5e0191e3b56ddb8921abb6a90e30/qiskit/circuit/library/standard_gates/x.py#L1098)